# Getting a ROS distribution value through c++ code

Tags: c++, ros

Is there a way to get the ROS_DISTRO in c++, cz I want to run specific C++ code when ros_distro is melodic, and else if noetic then this code.
Ubuntu: 20.04
Thank You.

Comment: yes, you are right, but the thing is if someone run my code from ubuntu 18.04 which use melodic, and 20.04 which use noetic, in both system my code should work. That is what I am asking if there any command like in python I do like this
`if os.environ['ROS_DISTRO'] == 'noetic':`

Comment: Get the answer. If any one want this in future. Here is the link. [link](https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/c-programming/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-linux-command-in-c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you can simply use `getenv()` to grab environmental variables.

```
import <iostream>
int main(){
    std::string distro = getenv("ROS_DISTRO");
    std::cout << "Got distro: " << distro << std::endl;
}
```